# Error in Android Studio xml

Tags: android, xml

Today i just update my android studio...In that i faced more error in the xml file

> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: attribute
>   \u0027android:contentScrim\u0027 not found.","sources": 
>   [{"file":"C:\Users\priya\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main6.xml","position":{"startLine":12}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"} AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: \u0027attr/actionBarSize\u0027
>   is incompatible with attribute android:layout_height (attr)
>   dimension|enum [fill_parent\u003d4294967295,
>   match_parent\u003d4294967295,
>   wrap_content\u003d4294967294].","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\priya\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main6.xml","position":{"startLine":22}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"} AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: attribute
>   \u0027android:srcCompact\u0027 not
>   found.","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\priya\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main6.xml","position":{"startLine":61}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"} AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: attribute
>   \u0027android:srcCompact\u0027 not
>   found.","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\priya\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main6.xml","position":{"startLine":99}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"} AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: attribute
>   \u0027android:srcCompact\u0027 not
>   found.","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\priya\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main6.xml","position":{"startLine":144}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: attribute
>   \u0027android:srcCompact\u0027 not
>   found.","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\priya\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main6.xml","position":{"startLine":182}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: attribute
>   \u0027android:srcCompact\u0027 not
>   found.","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\priya\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main6.xml","position":{"startLine":227}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

  > Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 29s

I try to rectify it but i cannot...anyone know about this...Thanks

---

This is my activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.kara.kavin.myapplication.Main6Activity">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/collasingtoolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="exitUntilCollapsed|scroll"
    android:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:title="NEAT Patrol"
    app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
    app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
    android:background="@drawable/sam">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbarid"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="attr/actionBarSize"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="#fcfcfc"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/ll">
        <LinearLayout
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:id="@+id/bankcardId"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="64dp"
                        android:layout_height="64dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundpurple"
                        android:srcCompact="@drawable/ic_attach_money_black_24dp"
                        android:padding="10dp"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Banking"/>
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@color/lightgray"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Check your bank activities"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="64dp"
                        android:layout_height="64dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundpink"
                        android:srcCompact="@drawable/ic_lightbulb_outline_black_24dp"
                        android:padding="10dp"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Ideas"/>
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@color/lightgray"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Check your bank activities"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="64dp"
                        android:layout_height="64dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundgreen"
                        android:srcCompact="@drawable/ic_control_point_black_24dp"
                        android:padding="10dp"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Add"/>
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@color/lightgray"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Check your bank activities"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="64dp"
                        android:layout_height="64dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundyello"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:srcCompact="@drawable/ic_attach_file_black_24dp" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Links"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@color/lightgray" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Check your bank activities"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_width="340dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="64dp"
                        android:layout_height="64dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundpurple"
                        android:srcCompact="@drawable/ic_wifi_black_24dp"
                        android:padding="10dp"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Add"/>
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@color/lightgray"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Check your bank activities"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: add activity_main6.xml file

Answer (score 1):

Use **app namespace** (in your collapsing toolbar)
So use,

```
 app:contentScrim="@color/your_color"
```

instead of

```
 android:contentScrim
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix three things that AAPT is pointing out to you:

- `attr/actionBarSize is incompatible with attribute android:layout_height` - you passed a string instead of a reference. Change `attr/actionBarSize` to `@attr/actionBarSize`
- `android:srcCompact not found` - there is no such thing as srcCompact :) replace `android:srcCompact` with `android:srcCompat` in all four places in your `activity_main6.xml`
- `android:contentScrim not found` - there's no contentScrim in the android namespace. You probably meant `app:contentScrim` like @santanu-sur already pointed out in his answer.

Fix these three issues and it should compile.

Comment: Did you fix all of these things? If you have, you must be getting different errors now - perhaps similar but about other resources or different files.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the style attr from my VIEW and problem solved.